# How to write integration tests in Scala Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration tests for my connector and i keep getting nullPointerException being trown here

`val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("todoCollection")`

here is my connector

```
package connectors

import org.bson.types._
import org.mongodb.scala.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.model.{Filters, FindOneAndUpdateOptions, ReturnDocument}
import org.mongodb.scala.result.{DeleteResult, InsertOneResult}
import play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents
import repositories.MongoRepository
import utils.LoggerUtil

import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class MongoConnector @Inject()
(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
mongoRepository: MongoRepository) extends LoggerUtil{

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = controllerComponents.executionContext
  def createTask(document: Document): Future[InsertOneResult] = {
    mongoRepository.collection.insertOne(document).toFuture().recover{
      case exception: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"[MongoConnector][createTask] - an unexpected error occurred while creating a new item: ${exception.getMessage}")
        throw new Exception(s"an unexpected error occurred while creating a new item: ${exception.getMessage}")
    }
  }

  def getAllTasks: Future[Seq[Document]] = {
    mongoRepository.collection.find().toFuture().recover{
      case exception: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"[MongoConnector][getAllTasks] - an unexpected error occurred: ${exception.getMessage}")
        throw new Exception(s"an unexpected error occurred: ${exception.getMessage}")
    }
  }

  def getOneTask(id: ObjectId): Future[Option[Document]] = {
    mongoRepository.collection.find(Filters.equal("_id", id)).headOption().recover{
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"[MongoConnector][getOneTask] - could not retrieve item: ${e.getMessage}")
        throw new Exception(s"could not retrieve item with id: $id ${e.getMessage}")
    }
  }

  def updateOneTask(id: ObjectId, document: Document): Future[Document] = {
    mongoRepository.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      Filters.equal("_id", id), document, FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER)
    ).toFuture().recover{
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"[MongoConnector][updateOneTask] - could not update item: ${e.getMessage}")
        throw new Exception(s"could not update item: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
  }

  def deleteTask(id: ObjectId): Future[DeleteResult] = {
    mongoRepository.collection.deleteOne(Filters.equal("_id", id)).toFuture().recover{
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"[MongoConnector][deleteTask] - could not delete item: ${e.getMessage}")
        throw new Exception(s"could not delete item: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
  }
}
```

here is my MongoRepository

```
package repositories

import org.mongodb.scala._
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents

import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class MongoRepository @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents, configuration: Configuration) {
  lazy val mongoUri: String = configuration.get[String]("mongoDatabase.uri")
  lazy val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(mongoUri)
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = controllerComponents.executionContext

  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("todoDatabase")

  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("todoCollection")

}
```

here are my tests

```
package it.connectors

import connectors.MongoConnector
import org.mongodb.scala.{Document, MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures.convertScalaFuture
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents
import play.api.test.Injecting
import play.api.{Application, Configuration}
import repositories.MongoRepository

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class MongoConnectorISpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with Injecting{

  override lazy val app: Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .configure(Map(
      "mongoDatabase.uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDatabase"
    ))
    .build


  lazy val configuration: Configuration = app.injector.instanceOf[Configuration]

  val testMongoRepository: MongoRepository = new MongoRepository(stubControllerComponents(), configuration) {
      override implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = stubControllerComponents().executionContext
      override lazy val mongoUri: String =  configuration.get[String]( "mongoDatabase.uri")
      override lazy val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(mongoUri)
      override val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDatabase")
      override val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("testCollection")
    }




  val testMongoConnector: MongoConnector = new MongoConnector(stubControllerComponents(), testMongoRepository)

    "MongoConnector" should {
    "return all items" when {
      "no errors happen in the database" in {
        println(Console.GREEN + testMongoRepository.mongoUri + Console.RESET)
        println(Console.GREEN + testMongoRepository.database.name + Console.RESET)
        println(Console.GREEN + testMongoRepository.collection.namespace + Console.RESET)
        testMongoConnector.getAllTasks.futureValue mustBe ""
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I am trying to set up a test database to use for my integration tests, but i cant figure out how to do it.

I am however able to successfully run the tests on the `todoDatabase` by directly injecting the MongoConnector as

`val mongoConnector = inject[MongoConnector]`

Can Anyone help?
here is the link to the repo if anyone wants to pull it down locally https://github.com/derickdamoah/todoList/pull/1